# PHP Foreach Duplicates - GameQ

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am trying to create a game server PHP script using [GameQ](http://gameq.sourceforge.net/) to work with my [XenForo](https://xenforo.com/), as there isn't one I like.

I have it nearly working, but I am getting duplicates in the foreach.
Below is the code I have, I have stripped out nearly all the html code, so it is mainly the PHP code.

```
    <?php

require '../GameQ.php';

$servers = array(
    array('id' => 'CSGO 1','type' => 'csgo','host' => '130.185.144.100:27015'),
    array('id' => 'CSGO 2','type' => 'csgo','host' => '173.199.73.230:27015'),  
    array('id' => 'Minecraft 1','type' => 'minecraft','host' => '85.236.100.111:28365'),
);

$gq = new GameQ();
$gq->addServers($servers);
$gq->setOption('timeout', 4); // Seconds
$gq->setFilter('normalise');
$results = $gq->requestData();

foreach ($results as $game) {   
    $game = $game['gq_type'];
    echo $game . '<br>';

    foreach ($results as $key => $server) {
        if ($server['gq_type'] == $game) {
            if ($server['gq_joinlink'] !='') {
                echo $server['gq_joinlink'] . '<br>';
            }
            echo $server['gq_hostname'] . '<br>';
            echo $server['gq_numplayers'] . '<br>';
            echo $server['gq_maxplayers'] . '<br>';
            echo $server['gq_mapname'] . '<br>';
            echo $server['gq_address'] . '<br>';
            echo $server['gq_port'] . '<br><br>';
        }
    }
    echo '<br><hr><br>';
}

?>
```

This is outputing, but you will see it is outputting a duplicate of the csgo servers.

csgo
steam://connect/130.185.144.100:27015/
[MG-1] Mestro Surf | Beginner - Learn2Surf | High TR | FastDL
14
48
surf_mom
130.185.144.100
27015

steam://connect/173.199.73.230:27015/
RivalTide.com Community Server by GameServers.com
0
30
de_dust
173.199.73.230
27015

---

csgo
steam://connect/130.185.144.100:27015/
[MG-1] Mestro Surf | Beginner - Learn2Surf | High TR | FastDL
14
48
surf_mom
130.185.144.100
27015

steam://connect/173.199.73.230:27015/
RivalTide.com Community Server by GameServers.com
0
30
de_dust
173.199.73.230
27015

---

minecraft
Welcome to a Multiplay Server!
0
8
world
85.236.100.111
28365

---

Can anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: why are you perfoming two intertwined foreach loops on the same array ?

Comment: As I am not sure how foreach nested is meant to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over the same array twice:

```
foreach ($results as $game) {
```

and

```
foreach ($results as $key => $server) {
```

I think the second loop should be

```
foreach ($game as $key => $server) {
```

#### Edit

Taking the second foreach out of the code:

```
foreach ($results as $server) {
    $game= $server['gq_type'];
    echo $game. '<br>';

    if ($server['gq_type'] == $game) {
        if ($server['gq_joinlink'] !='') {
            echo $server['gq_joinlink'] . '<br>';
        }
        echo $server['gq_hostname'] . '<br>';
        echo $server['gq_numplayers'] . '<br>';
        echo $server['gq_maxplayers'] . '<br>';
        echo $server['gq_mapname'] . '<br>';
        echo $server['gq_address'] . '<br>';
        echo $server['gq_port'] . '<br><br>';
    }
    echo '<br><hr><br>';
}
```

That will stop it echoing twice.

Comment: This outputs

csgo


csgo


minecraft

Comment: When using the above from Richard it is not passing through the details to the second foreach